# Cant delete/drop columns from multiple files through looping in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing some issue while trying to drop columns from multiple excel files in Python. I get the below error, when I am trying the same code on single file it works, but it doesn't work on multiple files while looping and I don't undersand why the error is `[columns ] not found in axis` . I am not sure what is the problem with my code. Any help much appreciated.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
folder = (r"C:\Users\kc\Documents\Extracted")


for file in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df2 = df.drop(columns=['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute', 'ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right'], axis=1)
   
    
df2.to_excel(file.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5d2d70719121> in <module>
     12     cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace('.','-'))
     13     df.columns = cols
---> 14     df2 = df.drop(columns=['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute', 'ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right'], axis=1)
     15 
     16 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4161                 weight  1.0     0.8
   4162         """
-> 4163         return super().drop(
   4164             labels=labels,
   4165             axis=axis,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3885         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3886             if labels is not None:
-> 3887                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3888 
   3889         if inplace:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3919                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3920             else:
-> 3921                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3922             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3923 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5280         if mask.any():
   5281             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5282                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5283             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5284         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute'\n 'ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan'\n 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right'\n 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right'] not found in axis
```

Comment: Print out the filename in your loop,  see which file is missing the columns. If you output the excel files to the same folder your script will fail the next time your run it as the columns are no longer there. You can prevent this with `errors=ignore` in your df.drop.

Comment: Hi I have checked inside the files by looping through the files ```for file in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    if set(['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute', 'ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right']).issubset(df.columns):
        print("exist")
    else:
        print("No")``` I see all files contains the columns. But I didn't know where to make changes if I want to save the files in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely the case that an `xlsx` file in the `extracted` folder does not have the columns that you are wishing to drop. Try adding a filter condition to process the rest of the files and also print the name of the file(s) without the columns.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
folder = (r"C:\Users\kc\Documents\Extracted")


for file_name in Path(folder).glob('*.xlsx'):
  df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
  drop_list = ['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute','ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 
'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right']
    
  if all(item in drop_list for item in list(df.columns)):
       df = df.drop(columns=drop_list, axis=1)
  else:
       print(file_name)
       df.to_excel(file_name.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)
```

This way you can process the rest of your files and also print the suspect files that might not have the columns you are looking to drop.
Also try not use `file` as your variable as it is a reserved keyword in python.

Comment: Hi Thank you! I tried this code but I get this error and it doesn't print any file name. Also I checked all files every file has this columns ```<ipython-input-25-2fd13376> in <module>
     11     drop_list = ['BarrierFreeAttributes.BarrierFreeAttribute','ConsultationHours.ConsultationHoursTimeSpan', 
     12 'Location.Coordinates.Latitude_right', 'Location.Coordinates.Longitude_right']
---> 13     if all(item in drop_list for item in df.columns.list):
     14         df2 = df.drop(columns=drop_list, axis=1)
     15     else
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'list'```

Comment: I have removed list from ```df.columns.list ``` now it works but strangly it prints all the file names in the folder even though the columns exist. I dont understand why. Any idea why?

Comment: There was an error in the snippet. I updated it. It should be `list(df.columns)` my apologies

Comment: Try `list(df.columns)`

Comment: I get a different error now and I don't understand why ```C:\Users\kc\Documents\Extracted\33098_DE.xlsx
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f3c580ce137d> in <module>
     14     else:
     15         print(file_name)
---> 16         df2.to_excel(file_name.with_suffix('.xlsx'),index = False)

NameError: name 'df2' is not defined```

Comment: The code doesn't give any error also it prints all the file names in the folder. But still doesn't drop the column names. I don't understand why. I also tried to save the files in csv format ```df.to_csv(file_name.with_suffix('.csv'),index = False)``` the code generates the csv files but doesn't drop the columns it intended to drop.

Comment: When I tried the same code on a single file it works very well. But it doesn't work while I am trying to iterate through the multiple files. I don't understand why.